# bin_random_table and RANDOM_BOOT_ID

Tags: linux, random

The Linux kernel has a few `sysctrl`'s related to random devices packaged in a `bin_random_table` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sysctl_binary.c?v=3.2):

```
static const struct bin_table bin_random_table[] = {
        { CTL_INT,      RANDOM_POOLSIZE,        "poolsize" },
        { CTL_INT,      RANDOM_ENTROPY_COUNT,   "entropy_avail" },
        { CTL_INT,      RANDOM_READ_THRESH,     "read_wakeup_threshold" },
        { CTL_INT,      RANDOM_WRITE_THRESH,    "write_wakeup_threshold" },
        { CTL_UUID,     RANDOM_BOOT_ID,         "boot_id" },
        { CTL_UUID,     RANDOM_UUID,            "uuid" },
        {}
};
```

I believe `RANDOM_UUID` is useful in cases `/dev/urandom` is not available, for example, in `chroot` environments. But I don't know how `RANDOM_BOOT_ID` is used.

What is the purpose of `RANDOM_BOOT_ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While RANDOM_UUID a type 4 (randomly-generated) UUID that changes every time it's read, RANDOM_BOOT_ID is a similar UUID that changes exactly once per boot. This is useful for configuration or instance differentiation to keep straight properties for your application that should change exactly once per boot.

This value is not typically significant for security or cryptography, but instead is used simply for instance management.

Also, **RANDOM_UUID is *not* a replacement for /dev/random**, but rather a source of properly-generated type-4 UUIDs. See how the first digit in the 3rd group is always "4"?

See also:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id
```

Comment: "RANDOM_UUID is not a replacement for /dev/random" - oh, I did not know that. I wanted to start a bounty and give you an extra 25 for that, but I can't at the moment. Hopefully I can get to it in the future. Thanks.